# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: o is not a function at this.setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm getting an error at this.setState. Do I have to bind the function? Or is there is a syntax issue? Can
someone please help?

```
    componentDidMount() {
    let mobile = false;
    this.setState({
        displayZipSearchPage : true,
        geolocation: {
            latitude: null,
            longitude: null,
            shared: false,
            supported: false,
        },
    });
    if (isNotEmptyObject(window) && 'navigator' in window) {
        if ('geolocation' in window.navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                (pos) => {
                    this.setState({  'The error occurs here'
                        geolocation: {
                            latitude: pos.coords.latitude.toString(),
                            longitude: pos.coords.longitude.toString(),
                            shared: false,
                            supported: true,
                        },
                    });
                },
                console.error,
                this.geoOptions,
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u share the error message first ?

Comment: @windmaomao    Uncaught TypeError: o is not a function
    at o (scheduler.production.min.js:11)
    at r (scheduler.production.min.js:12)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18)
    at zt (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
    at Zt (react-dom.production.min.js:123)
    at qt (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
    at Bo (react-dom.production.min.js:230)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.production.min.js:132)
    at t.r.setState (react.production.min.js:12)
    at ZipSearchWirelessUnAuth.js:215

Comment: ZipSearchWirelessUnAuth.js component is the code i posted

Comment: Try to run your code unminified. The error logs you've presented in the comment are all point to minified files, so that could give you a false representation where the error might occur as the lines don't match up and the variables have different names. There is also no sign of a Promise in your presented code, nor do we know what `o` represents.

Comment: one suggestion, delete everything inside and make it `(pos) => {}`. And see if your code work.